# How to use helm to find files that match regex in subdirectory?

Tags: helm, find-file, helm-for-files

I had this functionality working until I recently revamped my init files.  Now, I can't figure out how to get it back.

I use helm-find-file (mapped to C-x C-f) for finding and opening files.  I used to be able to execute the following keystrokes to find the location of a file in a sea of subdirectories.  The following shows a sample project:

```
~/src/Bar/Bar.cpp
~/src/Foo/Foo.cpp
~/src/FooBar/FooBar.cpp
```

If I executed the following, the file ~/src/Foo/Foo.cpp would open.

```
C-x C-f ~/src/*/Foo.cpp  <return>
```

If I executed the following from my home directory, helm would let me select which file to open, either ~/src/Foo/Foo.cpp or ~/src/FooBar/FooBar.cpp

```
C-x C-f ~/src/*/Foo*
```

Since I revamped my init files, I can't figure out what setting I nixed.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to acheive this functionality again?

Comment: I don't think `helm-find-files` supports globs the way you describe (see `C-x C-f C-h m`). You can try `helm-find` (`C-x C-f C-c /`). See also `helm-locate` and `helm-projects-find-files`.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize.  My memory failed me.  Helm, as far as I am aware, does not support this functionality.  The configuration I was using was ido.  I use these two packages simultaneously for different purposes, and thought it was Helm that allowed me to find files inside a subdirectory.